# how to create page using page tag in windows phone7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
<!-- To interactively stop, pause, and play the media, the LoadedBehavior 
       property of the MediaElement must be set to "Manual". -->
<MediaElement Source="media\numbers.wmv" Name="myMediaElement" 
 Width="450" Height="250" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Stretch="Fill" 
 MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded"/>

<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="450" Orientation="Horizontal">

  <!-- Play button. -->
  <Image Source="images\UI_play.gif" MouseDown="OnMouseDownPlayMedia" Margin="5" />

  <!-- Pause button. -->
  <Image Source="images\UI_pause.gif" MouseDown="OnMouseDownPauseMedia" Margin="5" />

  <!-- Stop button. -->
  <Image Source="images\UI_stop.gif" MouseDown="OnMouseDownStopMedia" Margin="5" />

  <!-- Volume slider. This slider allows a Volume range between 0 and 1. -->
  <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"  >Volume</TextBlock>
  <Slider Name="volumeSlider" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="ChangeMediaVolume" 
   Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0.5" Width="70"/>

  <!-- Volume slider. This slider allows you to change the speed of the media playback. -->
  <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="5"  VerticalAlignment="Center">Speed</TextBlock>
  <Slider Name="speedRatioSlider" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="ChangeMediaSpeedRatio" 
   Value="1" Width="70" />

  <!-- Seek to slider. Ths slider allows you to jump to different parts of the media playback. -->
  <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="5"  VerticalAlignment="Center">Seek To</TextBlock>
  <Slider Name="timelineSlider" Margin="5" ValueChanged="SeekToMediaPosition" Width="70"/>

</StackPanel>
```

how to this page create for windows phone7 app using vs2010?

Answer (score 1):

Very odd question.
It seems you just copied XAML from a site and have no idea on how to build a WP7 App.

Please, start from [here](http://create.msdn.com)

Then download the [free SDK](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started)

And try to follow the [Quickstart](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts)

Then I'm sure you can manage to build your simple app by yourself!